# Same IF statement returns true value in one workbook; false in another even though it references the first

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I was testing out a formula in one worksheet, Highlights. After ascertaining it worked as expected, I moved it into the Analysis worksheet (in the same workbook). All I did then was add the reference "Highlights!" before the cells so that the formula was looking in the right place.

For some reason, this makes the formula change from a TRUE if statement into a FALSE one. This makes absolutely no sense to me. Does anyone have ideas?

```
=IF(FX5:FX1000="Guatemala",SUMIF(EX5:FB1000,"Development multilateral: grant",FK5:FO1000),"wrong")
```

This is in the Highlights worksheet, and returns: #VALUE, which is correct (I still need to do some data clean up to make sure there are only numbers reported)

```
=IF(Highlights!FX5:FX1000="Guatemala",SUMIF(Highlights!EX5:FB1000,"Development multilateral: grant",Highlights!FK5:FO1000),"wrong")
```

The result: wrong

What on earth is going on here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is analysis in another workbook or worksheet?

Comment: By tab, I meant worksheet. Just clarified that on the question above! But yes, both of the worksheets are in the same workbook

Answer (score 0):

please try:

the problem is that you're 995 answers here in and it can only display the first one.

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(EX5:FB1000="Development multilateral: grant")*(EX5:FB1000)),"wrong")
```

must be entered with CTL+Shift+Enter

Comment: Just tried it, but it still returns "wrong" as the answer...?

Comment: No - that sumproduct isn't evaluating all of the necessary criteria. I tried this: =SUMPRODUCT((FX5:FX1000="Guatemala")*(EX5:FB1000="Private equity investment (company/internal resources)")*(FK5:FO1000)) but it didn't work either, probably because I'm comparing one column against multiple column arrays

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to sum up, but maybe these formulas will work for you:

```
=SUMIFS(EX5:FB1000,FK5:FO1000,"Development multilateral: grant",FX5:FX1000,"Guatemala")
```

and

`=SUMIFS(Highlights!EX5:FB1000,Highlights!FK5:FO1000,"Development multilateral: grant",Highlights!FX5:FX1000,"Guatemala")`